# Why am I getting “namespace is locked” in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Here is the issue: I've to add some global variables to a package, curiously, when I check it using the terminal, the package passes, however, when checking using RStudio, it throws an error. Does anyone have a clue on this? A similar question was put forward [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321927/trying-to-use-globalvariables-to-pass-binding-check-but-the-namespace-for-pack), but without help.

```
Error in registerNames(names, package, ".__global__", add) : 
  The namespace for package "SciencesPo" is locked; no changes in the global variables list may be made.
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... FUN -> eval -> eval -> globalVariables -> registerNames
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

These are my global variables:

```
globalVariables(names=c(".temp", 'var.order', 'var.class',
      'var.size', 'x_x', 'x_y'), package="SciencesPo")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you do with your data / variables?

If you e.g. override your data, it is needed to change the default of add in the function globalVariables to FALSE.

```
globalVariables(names=c(".temp", 'var.order', 'var.class',
  'var.size', 'x_x', 'x_y'), package="SciencesPo", add=F)
```